# Parse another script's output

Tags: bash

I'd like to do a script which, among other stuff, grabs the output of git branch and gets the selected branch. The typical output would be:

```
master
develop
* release-1.0
...
```

And I would want to get:

```
release-1.0
```

I guess it could be done using pipes, but I have not a single clue. Could you mates help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "The typical exit", you mean the output right?

Comment: Oh god, I couldn't remember how was this called. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the plumbing instead:

```
branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD)
```

git branch's output is considered porcelain and is not recommended for use in scripts.

Comment: And massage it with sed to remove the refs/heads portion: sed -e 's,.*/,,'

Comment: Whoa, I didn't know that. Could sed be piped too?

Answer (score 1):

```
line=$(git branch|grep '*')
echo ${line#* }
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I needed. However, @holygeek has the answer and an advice!